# Combining various results from various queries/tables/views in summary table

Tags: sql, merge, view, union

I've been pulling data from several different databases to create a summarised table of information all hinging on specific columns that they would have in common.

All of the tables have 3 columns in common:

Year
Month
Client

Other than this, they are a mixture of counts,sums,calculations and just general queries on various aspects of a client. I'm trying to map out a basic summary page on how each client is. My dream was to pull all of this into a centralised DB, with detailed information intact into tables. Then to have a series of views on each of these to summarise these tables 1 view per table. Then to have a summary table/view grouping all the views by year/month/client.

However i'm struggling to put everything together, I've got raw data in the tables like.

Ordernumber / Lines/ Client/Year/Month

with the view doing:

Count of orders / sum of lines / client/year/month.

However due to the variation with the views I can't do something like a UNION.

Example data (of the views)

```
View1 

Year    Month   Count   Sum         ClientCode
2017    May     18      146         A
2017    May     7       110         B
2017    May     2       17          C

View2
Year    Month   CountOfOrders   CountOfFiles    SumOfLines  ClientCode
2017    May                 8              2           140    A
2017    May                 7              6           25     B
```

Dream goal would be:

```
Year Month ClientCode Count Sum CountOfOrders CountOfFiles SumOfLines 
2017 May   A          18    146 8             2            140
2017 May   B          7     110 7             6            25
2017 May   C          2     17  0             0            0
```

Any advice would be great, I've tried doing a UNIONALL, so that I could do WHERE ALL_TABLES = Year 2017, Month = May. But realised that UNION's won't work as they merge rows now columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join views just like tables... Seems a `LEFT JOIN` is what you want here, with `COALESCE()` to handle nulls:

```
SELECT V1.Year, V1.Month, V1.ClientCode, V1.Count, V1.Sum, 
       COALESCE(CountOfOrders,0) COALESCE(CountOfFiles,0) COALESCE(SumOfLines,0)
FROM View1 V1
LEFT JOIN View2 V2 ON V1.Year = V2.Year
                   AND V1.Month = V2.Month
                   AND V1.ClientCode = V2.ClientCode
```

Only thing to note, you will need more logic if not there are `Year/Month/ClientCode` combinations that exist in View2, and aren't in View1.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. :) I tried this previously but I guess I tried throwing 15 tables together in one go was a bit much. This is working for 2 so i'll continue to build view and keep going.

Comment: @Alphaturian Ha, that happens to all of us, but I'm glad this worked for you.  If all the views/tables have the `Year/Month/ClientCode` relation, you should consider pulling a distinct list of all the possible combinations in your `FROM table`, then `LEFT JOIN` all the other views to the base one.  It'll keep things clean and help make sure you don't drop records along the way.

Comment: Hi Aaron, i've got a static table with: Year/Month/ClientCode, however when i've got that as the 1st table, and then the 2 views added in as left joins, even though they are linked on left joins from the static table, it's not quite working. Do I need them to all left outer join to each other aswell?

Comment: @Alphaturian Nope, just to the base table will be correct, as long as it is a distinct list to prevent duplication.  You should however, change your select to grab Year/Month/ClientCode from the first table, and then you will probably need to `COALESCE()` the Count and Sum columns from View1.

Comment: @Alphaturian If that isn't the issue, (I'm just guessing it is) you'll have to explain what part isn't quite working.

Comment: Scratch that, all working fine. I simply accidentally used the code from view 1 to join for view 2, and copied badly...

Comment: @Alphaturian Hahaha.. it happens :)